# Selecting an element by a class using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html snippit;

```
<input name='first' class="foo" />
<input name='second' class="foo bar" />
<input name='third' class="foo" />
```

I want to set the value of a specific element, but i'm unable to select the right one. This is whar i've tried:

```
jQuery('.bar').val('selected');
```

Comment: This works ... http://jsfiddle.net/by45U/

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine, make sure you are running on dom ready.

```
$(function() {
    $('.bar').val('selected');
});
```